# MediaStore.Images.Media does not delete the moved image entry

Tags: android, kotlin, mediastore

I've moved a picture from Download directory to DCIM by the app named 'Files'.

Cursor gets both, new and old paths.

```kotlin
getApplication<Application>().applicationContext.contentResolver.query(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            null,//projection,
            null,//selection,
            null,//selectionArgs,
            null//sortOrder
        )?.use { cursor ->
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                DatabaseUtils.dumpCurrentRow(cursor)
            }
       }
```

New record:

```
 10 {
    instance_id=null
    duration=null
    description=null
    picasa_id=null
    latitude=null
    date_expires=null
    _display_name=240x135.7.jpg
    datetaken=null
    mime_type=image/jpeg
    _id=38
    _data=/storage/1B07-1103/DCIM/240x135.7.jpg
    _hash=null
    _size=8037
    title=240x135.7
    width=240
    longitude=null
    is_trashed=0
    group_id=-1332787703
    document_id=null
    is_pending=0
    date_added=1596322655
    mini_thumb_magic=null
    primary_directory=DCIM
    secondary_directory=null
    isprivate=null
    original_document_id=null
    bucket_id=-1508016675
    relative_path=DCIM/
 }
```

The old one still exist:

```
 5 {
    instance_id=null
    duration=null
    description=null
    picasa_id=null
    latitude=null
    orientation=null
    height=135
    is_drm=0
    bucket_display_name=Download
    owner_package_name=com.android.chrome
    volume_name=external_primary
    date_modified=1596220214
    date_expires=null
    _display_name=240x135.7.jpg
    datetaken=null
    mime_type=image/jpeg
    _id=29
    _data=/storage/emulated/0/Download/240x135.7.jpg
    _hash=null
    _size=8037
    title=240x135.7
    width=240
    longitude=null
    is_trashed=0
    group_id=-1332787703
    document_id=null
    is_pending=0
    date_added=1596220214
    mini_thumb_magic=null
    primary_directory=Download
    secondary_directory=null
    isprivate=null
    original_document_id=null
    bucket_id=540528482
    relative_path=Download/
 }
```

How to delete old record with path to wrong location?
The first record leads to an error when trying to get a picture:

```kotlin
imageView.setImageURI(
              ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                       MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                       cursor.getLong(
                                      cursor.getColumnIndex(
                                                    MediaStore.Images.Media._ID
                                      )
                       )
              )
```

Or may be some way to check deleted file or not?

Test Android emulator API 29.

Comment: Well then that is a short coming of Google Files app. They should be ashamed. Call them to correct it.

Comment: `MediaStore.Images.Media does not delete the moved image entry` You are blaming the MediaStore. But then you say its the Files app. Confusing.

Comment: What other way is there to access public shared folders besides the media store? What can google files use to move files?

Comment: Before answering that question i would like you to react in my comments.

Comment: This question is the react to you comment. In new api there is no other way to access files in public shared directories. Direct access to /cdcard/Public/Downloads forbidden by Google. Only through MediaStore (or other content providers).

Comment: It is forbidden for your app. But do you really think that Google forbid it its own Files app? Even your app can still get full classic File access if you add legacyExternalStorage true to manifest file under Android Q. Its only one bit set or not.

Comment: It does not change anything. MediaStore can find new files. Why it cannot find deleted ones? The MediaStore continues to store stale data. Is there a way to update MediaStore data? How to check if a file has been deleted? It is not blaming. This is an attempt to find a solution not to display empty images.

Comment: I do not understand your problem anymore. You first said ms found deleted files. And now you say that it cannot find deleted ones.

Comment: Reboot your device to update the store.

Comment: Many times. Deleted files still in MediaStore database.

Comment: Any way, reboot is not solution. User couldnot reboot his device every time it move picture from one to another directory.

Comment: I think you understand that MediaStore continue keep stale database records for deleted files.

Comment: It remembers and saves deleted files so you can undo the delete. Is that what you mean? Where would they be stored?

Comment: How to undo the delete? How to know the file is deleted?

Comment: Initial question: Or may be some way to check deleted file or not?